# Is there a term for a "placeholder" word (like Acme Widgets) that isn't a "euphemism" as such?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm after a word similar to "euphemism" but without the negative/taboo nature of a euphemism, more of a generic term. I would characterise it as a "anony-nym" but that's not a thing!

For example:

"Acme Widgets" in place of a specific company name, e.g. "When I worked for Acme Widgets, I had a situation where I had to..."

"Jane Doe" in place of a specific person, e.g. "The website sees that Jane Doe has logged in, and gives a personalised list of music that Jane has listened to recently."

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please remember to show your initial attempts at research, even if it is just a simple web search— which might have turned up that, in fact, *[placeholder](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2016/01/placeholder-names/)* or *[placeholder name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placeholder_name)* may be the term you're looking for.

Comment: "fill in the blank" is sometimes used to describe that sort of thing ... or xyz

Comment: You could use *pseudonym* perhaps. But the noun from *anonymous* is actually [*anonym*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/anonym).

Comment: Arguably, *Acme Widgets* and *Jane Doe* are (stereotypical, conventional) [***syndoches***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche) standing in for the general classes they represent (*any* ordinary company or person). As with AI researchers today, who often talk about ***paper clips*** when they just mean *any product which could be made by a robot, but which we don't necessarily want too many of*.

Comment: "widget" is a dummy name for a thing that I've heard used; the Jane Doe of objects.

Comment: How about _demo_ word, one standing in until the real thing comes along?

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that "placeholder" is *exactly* the word you are looking for.

Wikipedia suggests in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placeholder_name#Linguistic_role) that "kadigan" or "cadigan" has also been used for the specific sense you are using, of a generic name or word that stands in for another one that is irrelevant or forgotten.  That's fun to know, and technically closes a semantic gap, but if you want people to actually know what you're talking about then I wouldn't recommend using it.

An analogous idea that I love from computer programming is that of [metasyntactic variables](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/M/metasyntactic-variable.html).

Answer (score 0):

For replacements on the word Euphemism, one can use **circumlocution** or **pseudonym**.

*[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/circumlocution)*

> **circumlocution** *n.* a roundabout or indirect way of speaking; the use of more words than necessary to express an idea.

*[Merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pseudonym)*

> **pseudonym** *n.* a fictitious name

If you're looking for examples of those in the context of a company you can use "XYZ" as some said in the comments, but I like to have some fun with it. How about:

- **Wal-mart's Little Brother**
- **McDonald's Version 2**
- **Gluttony with 4 walls and a cashier**

when referring to bloated companies with a negative connotation. For positive, smaller businesses, you could go for:

- **Mom and Pop Shop**
- **quaint boutique on Main Street**(used non-literally).